# awk + how to read CSV file with quotation mark

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, ksh

I have the following  line in the CSV file

```
   1,LINUX,"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2","root passowrd"
```

after I remove the separators "," by sed

I want now to read each field from the line

```
#  echo 1  LINUX "/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2" "root passowrd"  | awk '{print $1}'
1

#  echo 1  LINUX "/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2" "root passowrd"  | awk '{print $2}'
LINUX

#  echo 1  LINUX "/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2" "root passowrd"  | awk '{print $3}'
/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters
```

the expected result on the third field  should be **"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2"**

Please advice how to read the field in order to get all the words between the Quotation mark ,

what need to add in my awk command ?

So In case of single word then awk should print only this word
In case awk see words between the quotation mark then awk should print all the word between the quotation mark

- remark each field in the CSV could be with  Quotation mark or without , 
  for example the first field could be with 3 words as “ one two three” or maybe the first field could be only with one word  , awk should support both cases

Comment: did you want to get the values between `"` and `,`?

Comment: I guess your `echo`s miss the comma separating fields. If so, `cut -d',' -f3` would make it, as it will extract the 3rd field based on comma delimiter.

Comment: @fedorqui he removed the commas through sed. If he didn't do that, it would be so easy to extract the datas. Still i didn't know what he means.

Comment: OK I agree with you and I will not remove the commas from the line , so the solution in this case will be simple ? to use cut -d ',' -fx

Comment: OR use could use `,` as a Field Separator in awk.

Comment: ok just update your answer and I will vote for you , also please vote for me also

Comment: Updated my answer showing the `cut` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove the commas with sed: you are losing the "c" in the CSV (comma separated values) and things get more complicated. If so, you can use `cut` as this:

```
cut -d',' -f3
```

Examples:

```
$ cut -d',' -f3 <<< '1,LINUX,"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2","root passowrd"'
"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2"

$ cut -d',' -f3 <<< '1,LINUX,/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2,"root passowrd"'
/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2
```

It works for any case when fields are comma separated. Hence, you don't have to worry about the case of double quotes wrapping fields.

Answer (score 0):

In the below awk command, Field seperator is set to `"` so that we can get the string `/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2` easily by printing the column number 2. To inculde the double quotes, just add `FS` variable  while firing print command.

```
$ echo '1  LINUX "/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2" "root passowrd"'  | awk -F'"' '{print FS$2FS}'
"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2"
```

If you don't want `"` to be printed in the final result then try the below,

```
$ echo '1  LINUX "/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2" "root passowrd"'  | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2
```

If your input is like this `1,LINUX,"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2","root passowrd"`, then you could use `,` as a Field Separator to get the string `"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2"`

```
$ echo '1,LINUX,"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2","root passowrd"' | awk -F, '{print $3}' 
"/usr/cti/conf/apps/parameters  param1 param2"
```

Comment: your solution is good when you know that " exist , but in case we dont have " , then your awk isnt support this ( so need awk that support both - when " is exist and when it is not exist )

Comment: i don't know what you mean.

Comment: double quotes is the key. Without that how we post an answer.

Comment: I mean that the second field could be with only one string , and could be with more then one string with Quotation mark , do you have solution for that?

Comment: @maihabunash you'd better update your question giving more sample inputs, as well as a more generic explanation. In these comments it is quite complicated to understand what you mean.